# How to remove scrollbar in popup form

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="JS/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>External Form</h3>
        <a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myWufooModal">
            Please fill out my form.
        </a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myWufooModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" style="width:700px;">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <object type="text/html" data="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" style="width:640px;height:730px;">
                        </object>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when run this code in localhost, it works fine. When applying my site it will show scrollbar, I adjust width for corresponding CSS style, still stays scrollbar, May I know how to fix this?

Comment: you can use overflow : hidden property of css

Comment: may i know where is exact palce to add?

Comment: ok, it removed, but  content is not visible on the end.

Comment: If you have done overflow : hidden content will be hidden

Comment: ok, then to display the whole content, either you have to increase the height of your container or you have to show scroll for showing all the content

Comment: @SandeepPal: I i have added overflow-hidden in custom.css in container, so now look like this http://imgur.com/mSAcIEE

Comment: read docs for how overflow property works. if u have set fixed height of element and set overflow hidden, then if content have bigger height that u provide, part of content will be hidden.

Comment: not set, height:fixed

Answer (score 1):

**Problem with** `overflow:hidden` would be that it would hide the details from your form and depending on the screen size, different users will see different counts of columns in the form as teh overflowing content has been hidden.

What i would suggest is that you use  [**Media Queries**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)  on you pop up page and reduce the size (read *height*) of item in you form

Something like this would be my suggestion :

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  .form-textbox, .form-textarea {
       width: 250px;height:20px /* dummy size, use you own */
   }

}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
  .form-textbox, .form-textarea {
     width: 250px;height:20px  /* dummy size, use you own */
  }

}
```

Good Read on Media Q :  [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="modal-content" style="width:700px;">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <object type="text/html" data="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" style="width:640px;height:730px;">
            </object>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine in localhost, but in my site shows scrollbar. I have added overflow hidden in custom.css, it removed, but content will be cut on the right side, look like this imgur.com/mSAcIEE

Comment: `overflow:hidden` always hides the mess, miss...not cleans it!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor I know that and i have already said that in comment

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow` as `hidden`

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow:hidden">
<!--    Model Body-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="overflow:hidden">
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dubeynee/48aja4pz/)

Comment: `overflow:hidden` always hides the mess, mate...not cleans it!! :)